# Declare the same model twice - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I have two models and I am trying to declare each of the models twice, for some purposes.
for some reason, the second model cannot declare again, and when I am running this line - `Foo2.first.bar2` , Im getting an error: `undefined method 'bar2'`

The first model, however, running perfectly: `Foo1.first.bar1`

Any help will much appreciated.
Thanks, 
David

My models look like:

In my `appname/app/models/foo1.rb`:

```
class Foo1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    def bar1
        puts 'bar'
    end
end
```

In my `appname/app/models/foo2.rb`:

```
class Foo2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    def bar2
        puts 'bar2'
    end
end
```

In my `appname/config/initializers/main.rb` :

```
require "main_classes"
```

In my `appname/lib/main_classes.rb` :

```
class Foo1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :foo1_name
end

class Foo2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :foo2_name
end
```

When I remove the required line, it runs perfectly .. why ?

/========== updated =============/

I have 3 tables :  Tables, Columns, Funcs.

In Tables I have the table names, In Columns, the columns names, types etc. And in Funcs the Tables funcionality.

The code in `appname/app/func.rb` :

```
class Func < ActiveRecord::Base
    def foo
        puts 'bar'
    end
end
```

In `appname/config/initializers/main.rb` :

```
require "main_classes"
```

In `appname/lib/main_classes.rb`:

```
Table.find_each do |t|
    t.columns.where(accessible: true).find_each do |c|
        eval "class #{t.name.classify} < ActiveRecord::Base ;          attr_accessible :#{c.name.to_sym} ; end ;"
    end
end
```

The code Func.first.foo raise `undefined method 'bar'`

When I remove the required line, it runs perfectly .. why ?

Comment: "why?" - rails autoloading. Require those extensions at the top of your model files. If you're doing this, you might as well merge the definitions

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, Can you be more specific? Is there a way to make it work without changing the model files? (The reason I set it in 2 places is that my models are not static and are created dynamically by the user, so that there is need for a separate file to define the models functionality)

Comment: Ah, now it becomes interesting. So there's no file? Models are defined like `Class.new` or something? Show (simplified) code.

Comment: Well, It's complicated :). My main models are `Tables` and `Columns` (weird as it sound..)
When user insert a new record of table it creates new model, when he insert a new column, it add new attribute to the model. (by running rails generate).
The model functionality defined in a table called `Functions`  and I am runing it by running `eval "#{Function.body}"`, and to do so I have to declare the model again by running a loop of tables. Hope I explained it somehow..   Thanks, @SergioTulentsev

Comment: I don't think I totally understand what you're doing there, but since you're eval'ing some text, you surely can preprocess it, right? Insert the require statements, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I remove the required line, it runs perfectly .. why ?

As I have mentioned in comments, the answer is - rails autoloading mechanism.

When you reference a class (`Func` in your case), one of two things happen:

- if class with such name is loaded, it is returned
- if it is not loaded, rails tries to find it by looking for `func.rb` in its `$LOAD_PATH` directories. If it's still not found there, `LoadError` is raised.

In your case, `Func` is defined at application startup (when initializers run). So when you later do `Func.first.foo`, that plain `Func` with a couple of `attr_accessible` is returned. Your `app/models/func.rb` **won't ever be evaluated**.

Possible solution: configure eager loading of classes (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).